# Не могу поставить установить пакеты через ansible с помощью переменных

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible

У меня есть ansible скрипты для установки нужных мне приложений. Вот как выглядит `playbook`:

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  strategy: free

  tasks:
   - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
     become: true
     apt:
       upgrade: yes
       update_cache: yes
       cache_valid_time: 86400 #One day
   - name: hack to resolve Problem with MergeList Issue
     shell: 'find /var/lib/apt/lists -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -v {} \;'
   - name: update apt cache directly (apt module not reliable)
     shell: 'apt-get clean && apt-get update'
   - name: Preliminary installation
     apt:  name=apt-transport-https force=yes
   - name: Add the Google signing key
     apt_key: url=https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg  state=present
   - name: Add the k8s APT repo
     apt_repository: repo='deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main' state=present
   - name: update apt cache directly (apt module not reliable)
     shell: 'apt-get update'
   - name: Install packages
     apt: name={{ item }} state=present force=yes
     with_items: "{{ PACKAGES }}"
```

Проблема возникает в последней задаче при установке нужных мне пакетов. Ошибка:

```
TASK [Install packages] *******************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [192.168.77.11] (item=[u'vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io', u'kubelet', u'kubeadm', u'kubectl', u'kubernetes-cni']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": ["vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io", "kubelet", "kubeadm", "kubectl", "kubernetes-cni"], "msg": "No package matching 'vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io' is available"}
failed: [192.168.77.10] (item=[u'vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io', u'kubelet', u'kubeadm', u'kubectl', u'kubernetes-cni']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": ["vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io", "kubelet", "kubeadm", "kubectl", "kubernetes-cni"], "msg": "No package matching 'vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io' is available"}
failed: [192.168.77.12] (item=[u'vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io', u'kubelet', u'kubeadm', u'kubectl', u'kubernetes-cni']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "it---
```

Содержимое файла `vars.yml`:

```
---
PACKAGES:
  - vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io
  - kubelet
  - kubeadm
  - kubectl
  - kubernetes-cni
```

Пробовал заходить на разные машины по `ssh` и ставить пакеты через `apt-get`. Все успешно ставится и работает. Версия `ansible`: `2.8.5`. Сервера `Ubuntu 16.04`. Подскажите, что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- vim  - htop  - tmux  - docker.io` - это не 4 разных пакета. Это один пакет. Ты забыл добавить новых строк.